# How to pass delete id to API while using map in map function

Tags: reactjs

How can I post the delete id to the API server while using the *handleClick* map in map function?

In the case I can handle the joins table records, suppose I want to delete a record from child table how can I handle this situation.

```js
<tbody>
  {allRecords.map(record => (
     record.posts.map(post => (
        <AllRows
          key={record.id}
          record={record}
          post = {post}
          onDelete={this.handleDelete}
        />
    ))
  ))}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code

Comment: Pass the map index to handle click functions

Comment: You need to show the code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array object which looks like this

```js
const users = [
      { 
       name: 'Rohit',
       age: 18, 
       id: '22123'
      },
      { 
        name: 'Rohan', 
        age: 28, 
        id: '22124'
      },
      { 
        name: 'Rahul',
        age: 98,
        id: '22125'
      }
    ]

const newUser = users.map(user => {
  delete user.id 
  return user 
  })
  
console.log(newUser)
```

You can simply user delete object property from the user object in your map

Comment: Hey @iRohitBhatia. I'm not asking to delete  json data. How can I post my delete id from reactjs to API server

Comment: Your previous question without any code was vague so I answered it with my best assumption of what you wanted to achieve, going through it again and fixing it

Comment: *I can't delete my comment because of SFO restriction but your question still seems vague

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `id` to `handleDelete()` function.

```
<tbody>
  {allRecords.map(record => (
     record.posts.map(post => (
        <AllRows
          key={record.id}
          record={record}
          post = {post}
          onClick={() => this.handleDelete(record.id)}
        />
    ))
  ))}
</tbody>
```

For more details: [How To Delete An Item From An Array In React](https://vegibit.com/how-to-delete-an-item-from-an-array-in-react/)